# C++ While loop not re-assigning string value

Tags: c++, input, while-loop, iostream, c-strings

I had created a program that counts the amount of vowels in a provided string. It counts the vowels correctly and repeats when the user provides a 'y' or 'Y'. However, when it repeats, it automatically assigns "" to the C-string I am attempting to use.

```
int main()
{
    //Creating repeating decision
    char answer = 'y';

    while ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'))
    {

        //declaring our C-String
        char ourString[81] = "Default";

        //Prompting user for a string, storing it as a C-String
        std::cout << "Please enter a string!(Less than 80 characters please.)\n";
        std::cin.getline(ourString, 81);

        //Using a loop to count the amount of vowels
        int ourNum = 0;
        int vowels = 0;

        while (ourString[ourNum] != '\0')
        {
            switch (ourString[ourNum]) {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            case 'i':
            case 'I':
            case 'o':
            case 'O':
            case 'u':
            case 'U':
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                vowels++;
                ourNum++;
                break;
            default:
                ourNum++;
                break;
            }

        }
        std::cout << "The numbers of vowels in: \"" << ourString << "\" is " << vowels << "!\n";
        std::cout << "Do again? Please enter \"Y\" to repeat, or any other character to escape.";
        std::cin >> answer;

    }

}
```

Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @KaysKadhi answer is correct. In addition, now that you have working code, you can simplify the end of your `switch` statement too. All you need is `case 'Y': vowels++; default: ourNum++; break;` rather than a `break` after both the `case` and `default` statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After writing "y" and hitting the enter button both the "y" and the `"/n"` are stored in the input buffer, so the "y" goes to the answer char, and "/n" is considered the input of the next getline.
There are a few solutions to this. You could add a call to `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> yes`. Or you could make yes a string, and use `getline` instead of `operator>>` there.